# Where are all the Pokemon in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-pokemon

I've caught my [first few](http://googleasiapacific.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/become-pokemon-master-with-google-maps.html), around the starting area (Geneva), but I can't find any more. Where should I look next?

Comment: I don't understand the down votes here, why not leave a comment to explain yourself too? This is a legit question and game, it is not fake. Look for yourselves.

Comment: It's extremely broad. "Where are all the Pokémon?"

Comment: So its open for input, its within the rules here. This "game" won't be around for long most likely so just have fun with it.

Comment: @Dupree3 Something can be within the rules and still be flawed or not useful. That's why it has some downvotes but hasn't been closed/deleted.

Comment: This is just a giant list question

Comment: If you guys are still interested, there's sites now that list out where to find the pokemon in the Google Maps Challenge. http://googlemapspokemon.com/

Comment: You can find the most Pokémon around *Pokémon Labs*, which are found at the location of famous research institutes, such as the *CERN* in Geneva, the *Observatory* in Sydney, the *Charles Darwin Research Institute*, or the *Google Headquarters* (?)

Answer (score 6):

The best place to look is in the main cities where pokemon are.  Here is a map that is actually Japan.

[image]

[This website](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_world_in_relation_to_the_real_world) has more locations then the one I listed with actual city names.  Pokemon are most common where humans actually live.  You can find rare Pokemon outside main cities  of course, but it is a rare occurrence.

You can find lots of them around [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pokemon+Center+Yokohama/@35.45547,139.631556,648m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x60185c5d7366a111:0x9b5f440ae029ccc1) Pokemon center in Yokohama.  You might not be able to catch them because they are likely to already owned by other Pokemon Trainers.

Comment: Wow this is great. I didn't even know that Pokemon maps are actually based on real Japan.

Comment: @Jutschge: Not only Japan. Unova (Gen V) is based on New York City, Kalos (Gen VI) is based on France. The spin-off regions are also all based on real locations, but I don't know those...

Answer (score 2):

Search near all of the Google Headquarters. I found a lot in Sydney Australia and Mountain View CA

Comment: Also look at well-known places, i.e. Mt. Everest.  Airports also seem to be good for finding some of the flying types.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some at: Eiffle tower, white house, statue of liberty, big Ben tower, all over tokyo, harujuku station, Arc de triumph, google buildings around the world.

Answer (score 0):

I found a ton all over manhattan. Make sure to zoom in because some dont show up initially

Answer (score 0):

There is a Snorlax on I 280 near el monte rd (in CA).

Comment: Then you get fragmented answers like this one.

Answer (score -1):

Found about 30 around Sydney Australia - within a 10km radius from the pokemon lab at the Sydney Observatory